# How can i read and write an array of structures to a binary file in C

Tags: c, file, struct, fwrite, fread

I have a static array of structs and through a `void new_cinema()` function i want to get an info about a film and so on and write this info to the file and then using another function i want to read this info through the file. I've tried to do this:

```
FILE* file;
fpos_t current_position = 0;

struct cinema
{
    char name[256];
    char session[256];
    double price;
    int audience;
};

struct cinema october[25];  
int counter = 0;
int cntr[N] = { 0 };

void new_cinema()
{

    if (counter < N)
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            fopen_s(&file, "file.bin", "wb");
            if (file == NULL)
            {
                printf("An error occured1\n");
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (counter != 0)
        {
            fopen_s(&file, "file.bin", "ab");
            if (file == NULL)
            {
                printf("An error occured2\n");
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }
        }
        fsetpos(file, &current_position);
        printf("\nWrite the name of the movie:\n");
        gets_s(october[counter].name, 255);
        printf("\nEnter the session time:\n");
        scanf_s("%s", october[counter].session, 255);
        printf("\nEnter ticket price:\n");
        scanf_s("%lf", &october[counter].price);
        printf("\nEnter the number of viewers:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &october[counter].audience);
        fwrite(&october[counter], sizeof(struct cinema), 1, file);
        fgetpos(file, &current_position);
        counter++;
    }

    else
        printf("\nThe limit has gone!\n");
    fclose(file);
}
```

In this part of the code i create a `struct cinema` and then an array `october` of the `struct cinema` type. In the `new_cinema()` function if `counter` is zero, which means the user didn't actually create anything before i `fopen_s(&file, "file.bin", "wb");` and set the the position to zero `fsetpos(file, &current_position);`,  after that i get some info and write it to the file  `fwrite(&october[counter], sizeof(struct cinema), 1, file);` and then i get the current position and increment the `counter`.

I think that i'm doing all this wrong, firsty i'm not sure abot the
`fwrite(&october[counter], sizeof(struct cinema), 1, file);`, i don't know about the & because it is the array. Do i need & in here? Secondly, the `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()` when i get the current position and when the user enters `new_cinema()` again and `fsetpos` sets the position of indicator of stream i guess that after completeing receiving information about the movie and writing this info to the file, the last character of the previous structure can be rewritten to reflect the new information. Is it ?

And after doing all this, I try to read this information from the file, i wrote this code, but it is incorrect:

```
void read_struct()
{
    fopen_s(&file, "file.bin", "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("couldn't read the file\n");
        return;
    }
    struct cinema *testing;
    testing = (struct cinema*)malloc(sizeof(struct cinema) * 25);
    int i = 0;
    while(!feof(file))
    {
        fread(&testing[i], sizeof(struct cinema), 1, file);
        ++i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", testing[i].name);
        printf("%s\n", testing[i].session);
        printf("%lf", testing[i].price);
        printf("%d\n", testing[i].audience);
    }
}
```

Assistance is really appreciated!

Comment: You don't need a loop to write or read the data. The value `1` you pass to `fwrite` and `fread` is the number of elements you want to write or read. So e.g. `fwrite(october, sizeof october[0], 25, file)` will write all the data of the array in one go. Here `sizeof october[0]` is the element size, and `25` is the number of elements, and `october` will *decay* to a pointer to the first element (i.e. it's the same as `&october[0]`).

Comment: You show there's a global array `cinema october[25]`. Then, in reading, you start messing with dynamic allocation... Make life simple! Just write the entire blob of `october[]` to the file, and load the blob back into the same spot when loading... Disk space and memory are both vast and cheap. Use them while writing uncomplicated code. **Edit** This is what the programmer dude said, but simpler: `fwrite( october, sizeof october, 1, file );` One massive blob... (Same for `fread()` to load the blob...)

Comment: I'm not sure it's safe to write a struct as a blob to a file and expect to be able to read it in again without ever having problems. Different compilers or versions or hardware settings might pad the struct differently. Also, endianness issues might give you portability issues. I might be wrong about this, but I thought I'd share my thoughts.

Comment: @SimonGoater Noted, and you're right (in a larger frame of reference.) The OP demonstrates they are still learning to code and getting the basics down (i/o, indexing, parsing input safely without using `scanf()`...)... This "practice project" is a playground through which to explore, perhaps, `memmove()`, etc... The bigger picture concerns (eg: portability, 'endianess', 'packing') can & will be addressed when the OP doesn't give up in frustration and turn to Flower Arranging for a career... You are, however, quite right! All in good time... `:-)`